# How to integrate plot method into my class

Tags: python, class, matplotlib, object

I am trying to make an class with which I can make a s the histogram of any list and the plot of the data. My calculations run fine but the plot method does not seem to work. I would really appreciate your help here :)

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

class BasicStatistics:

    def __init__(self, list):
        self.list = list

    def mean(self):
        return sum(self.list) / len(self.list)

    def median(self):
        self.list.sort()
        if len(self.list) % 2 == 1:
            return self.list[len(self.list) // 2]
        else:
            return (self.list[len(self.list) // 2 - 1] + self.list[len(self.list) // 2]) / 2

    def var(self):
        avg = self.mean()
        var = sum((x - avg) ** 2 for x in self.list) / len(self.list)
        return var

    def std_dev(self):

        vari = self.var()
        std_dev = (vari) ** (1 / 2)
        return std_dev

    def norma(self):
        return [(i-self.mean()) / self.var() for i in self.list]

    def plot(self):
       fig, (axs1,axs2,axs3) = plt.subplots(2)
       axs1.hist(self.list)
       axs1.axvline(self.mean, color='red')
       axs1.axvline(self.median, color='black')
       axs1.axvline(self.mean - self.std_dev(), color='green')
       axs1.axvline(self.mean + self.std_dev(), color='green')
       axs2.plot(lst)
       plt.show()
```

Comment: When you call axs2.plot(lst), the variable lst is not defined, also you try to get 3 axes for a subplot of size 2. You cannot pass methods to matplotlib, you need to add (). And there are probably other errors. It is probably worth to look at the console output in order to find the bugs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a version that produces a plot, but I am not sure if it is what you want. See my comment to the question for identified errors.

Note that stackoverflow is for specific questions, not a place for others to debug code. It is possible that your question may finally get deleted.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

class BasicStatistics:

    def __init__(self, list):
        self.list = list

    def mean(self):
        return sum(self.list) / len(self.list)

    def median(self):
        self.list.sort()
        if len(self.list) % 2 == 1:
            return self.list[len(self.list) // 2]
        else:
            return (self.list[len(self.list) // 2 - 1] + self.list[len(self.list) // 2]) / 2

    def var(self):
        avg = self.mean()
        var = sum((x - avg) ** 2 for x in self.list) / len(self.list)
        return var

    def std_dev(self):

        vari = self.var()
        std_dev = (vari) ** (1 / 2)
        return std_dev

    def norma(self):
        return [(i-self.mean()) / self.var() for i in self.list]

    def plot(self):
       fig, (axs1,axs2) = plt.subplots(2)
       axs1.hist(self.list)
       axs1.axvline(self.mean(), color='red')
       axs1.axvline(self.median(), color='black')
       axs1.axvline(self.mean() - self.std_dev(), color='green')
       axs1.axvline(self.mean() + self.std_dev(), color='green')
       axs2.plot(self.list)
       plt.show()
       
aa = BasicStatistics([1,7,3, 4, 5, 3, 2])
aa.plot()
```

[image]

Comment: Help fix the question first, before posting an answer

Comment: @Mad Physicist , ok. I believe that this debug-my-code question cannot be improved and should be deleted since of no use for others (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/293931/should-one-answer-terribly-poor-questions). I just flagged it, but at least the OP, which is a new member, has a chance to fix his code.

Comment: Hello, Thank you for answering the question. This is my first time using StackOverflow so I was not sure how about the protocols here. Thank you again. My questions should have been more specific about how to use matplotlib as a method into a python class.